# How do I make my text parsing function more memory efficient/friendly?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, corpus

I am trying to preprocess a large corpus (around 2MB) in such a way that every word of the text is grouped according to the 2 words that follow it (i.e. in groups of 3s). So for the following input:
`'The man ate the apple'`, I'd obtain `(The, man, ate), (man, ate, the), (ate, the, apple)`. Then I want to vectorize each word, create a dataset (where the first two words are used as input and the third is the output) and feed it into an LSTM.

When running the following code on an instance in Google Compute Engine, the process is always killed when I increase the number of maximum words the (Keras) tokenizer accepts. Any ideas on how I could make my code more efficient?

```
size_of_vocabulary = 1000

def preprocess_corpus():

    text = load_corpus(filename)
    print("Preprocessing...")

    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=size_of_vocabulary)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts([text])

    word_index = tokenizer.word_index
    reverse_word_index = dict(zip(word_index.values(), word_index.keys()))  

    return text, word_index, reverse_word_index

def trie_data():

    def clean_text(text):
        filters = '!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n'
        translate_map = str.maketrans(filters, " " * len(filters))
        return text.translate(translate_map)

    def vectorize_word(word):
        word_vector = np.zeros(size_of_vocabulary-1).astype('float32')
        word_vector[word_index[word]] = 1.0
        return word_vector

    text, word_index, reverse_word_index = preprocess_corpus()
    clean_text = clean_text(text).split()

    X_data = list()
    Y_data = list()


    # Use generator (useful for large texts)
    def enumerate_data():
        for index, word in enumerate(clean_text):
            if index+2 < len(clean_text):
                if word_index[clean_text[index+2]] < size_of_vocabulary -1:
                    yield np.asarray([word_index[clean_text[index]], word_index[clean_text[index+1]]]), vectorize_word(clean_text[index+2])

    data = enumerate_data()
    for i in data:
        X_data.append(i[0])
        Y_data.append(i[1])

    return np.asarray(X_data), np.asarray(Y_data), word_index
```

Comment: Why is it *killed*?

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: One likely way is to translate the words to integers (lexicon index) immediately.  This would give you triples (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 4), etc.  This replaces strings with fixed-length integers.